# Not able to setup python logger properly

Tags: python, logging

Im trying to setup logging for my module:

Used the exact snippet hosted here:
https://gist.github.com/kingspp/9451566a5555fb022215ca2b7b802f19

logging.yaml:

```
    info_file_handler:
        class: logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
        level: INFO
        formatter: standard
        filename: /tmp/info.log
        maxBytes: 10485760 # 10MB
        backupCount: 20
        encoding: utf8
```

setup_logging.py

```py
    def setup_logging(default_path='logging.yaml', default_level=logging.INFO, env_key='LOG_CFG'):
        path = default_path
        value = os.getenv(env_key, None)
        if value:
            path = value
        if os.path.exists(path):
            with open(path, 'rt') as f:
                try:
                    config = yaml.safe_load(f.read())
                    logging.config.dictConfig(config)
```

Im initiating this in server.py as:
moto/server.py

```py
   setup_logging()
   logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
   logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
   logger.info("Logger SETUP successfully")
```

This logs the output to the /tmp/info.log appropriately but when I initialize the same in another file in a child module Im not seeing the logs getting written to the file:

moto/ec2/models.py

```py
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    def describe_internet_gateways(
        self,
        internet_gateway_ids=None,
        filters=None):
        igws = []
        #logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        #logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        print("\n\n\n\n\n{}\n\n\n\n\n".format(__name__))
        logger.info("in describe_internet_gateways")
        session = get_db_session()
        igws = session.query(InternetGateway_t)
```

But if I initialize the logger inside the method(if I uncomment the commented section inside the method above) then the logs are written appropriately in the /tmp/info.log file

Could someone please help me what Im missing out, how to initialize the logs only once and use it across modules?

Read and tried the logging module explanation from python docs, but Im stilling hitting the issue.

Edit-1:
Tried the solution below by @olinox14 below by doing the following edits:

logging.json

```
     "handlers": {
         "console": {
             "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
             "level": "DEBUG",
             "formatter": "standard",
             "stream": "ext://sys.stdout"
         },
         "info_file_handler": {
             "class": "logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler",
             "level": "INFO",
             "formatter": "standard",
             "filename": "/tmp/info.log",
             "maxBytes": 10485760,
             "backupCount": 20,
             "encoding": "utf8"
         },
         "error_file_handler": {
             "class": "logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler",
             "level": "ERROR",
             "formatter": "error",
             "filename": "/tmp/errors.log",
             "maxBytes": 10485760,
             "backupCount": 20,
             "encoding": "utf8"
         },
         "debug_file_handler": {
             "class": "logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler",
             "level": "DEBUG",
             "formatter": "standard",
             "filename": "/tmp/debug.log",
             "maxBytes": 10485760,
             "backupCount": 20,
             "encoding": "utf8"
         },
         "critical_file_handler": {
             "class": "logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler",
             "level": "CRITICAL",
             "formatter": "standard",
             "filename": "/tmp/critical.log",
             "maxBytes": 10485760,
             "backupCount": 20,
             "encoding": "utf8"
         },
         "warn_file_handler": {
             "class": "logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler",
             "level": "WARN",
             "formatter": "standard",
             "filename": "/tmp/warn.log",
             "maxBytes": 10485760,
             "backupCount": 20,
             "encoding": "utf8"
         }
     },
     "root": {
         "level": "NOTSET",
         "handlers": [
             "console",
         ],
         "propagate": true
     },
     "loggers": {
             "test": {
                     "level": "DEBUG",
                     "handlers": [
                             "console",
                             "info_file_handler",
                             "error_file_handler",
                             "critical_file_handler",
                             "debug_file_handler",
                             "warn_file_handler"
                     ],
                     "propagate": "no"
             }
     }
 }
```

But now Im seeing logs on console but not logged in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, named loggers are singletons. You setup a new logger each time you call a new name, and you retrieve the existing one if you call the reviously used name.

Here is a solution:

logging.yaml:

```
version: 1

formatters:
    standard:
        format: "%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"

handlers:
    info_file_handler:
        class: logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
        level: INFO
        formatter: standard
        filename: info.log
        maxBytes: 10485760 # 10MB
        backupCount: 20
        encoding: utf8

loggers:
    my_logger:
        level: DEBUG
        handlers: [info_file_handler]
        propagate: no
```

moto/server.py

```
import logging.config
import os

import yaml

from ec2 import models

def setup_logging(default_path='logging.yaml', default_level=logging.INFO, env_key='LOG_CFG'):
    path = os.getenv(env_key, None) or default_path
    try:
        with open(path, 'rt') as f:
            config = yaml.safe_load(f.read())
            logging.config.dictConfig(config)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        #... load the basic config here?
        pass

setup_logging()
logger = logging.getLogger("my_logger")
logger.info("Logger SETUP successfully")

models.f()
```

moto/ec2/models.py

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger("my_logger")

def f():
    logger.info("Logger called successfully")
```

Comment: Thanks @olinox14, tried the solution, but now seeing the output on the console but same is not being written to files.

Comment: have added the findings above.

Comment: I cannot help you if I don't have the config of the handlers, since they are responsible of outputting the logging messages into a file, the console, a database and so on... The handler above does write messages to ` info.log` file

Comment: Sure have added the details

Comment: You called the logger 'test' here, did you replace every `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` by `logger = logging.getLogger("test")` already?

Comment: Yes, olinox14 thats why Im able to get the output from models file too. Only problem now is the output not written to the log files

Comment: That's why i asked: it seems the 'root' logger is used, not the 'test' one. Or maybe tha handlers are not configured like they should, try to add the 'info_file_handler' to the root logger maybe? also does /tmp/ exists? Do you have right to write in it? Maybe try to remove the `/tmp/` part to let the file being created in the working directory?

Comment: 1. I have the rights to write to /tmp/ folder
2. If I add the handlers to root logger, it does write the logs to the files but I get the logs written twice, not sure why.

Comment: Written twice in file or in console?

Comment: Both in console and log file:
2019-09-11 06:18:31,114 - test - INFO - in describe_internet_gateways
2019-09-11 06:18:31,127 - test - INFO - in describe_internet_gateways

Comment: Go the issue, had to set propagate in loggers to false instead of "no", since it is json. Thanks for all the help olinox14